# B(R)/B(R)-Measurability

Tags: measure-theory

I am considering the measure space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), \lambda)$ and the function $u: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given as:

$u= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k} \mathbb{1}_{[k,k+1)}$

I am asked to:

a) Argue that $u$ is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable

Using the theorem below I have done the following:

> Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space. Every $\mathcal{A}/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable function $u: X \to \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ is the pointwise limit of simple functions $f_{n} \in \varepsilon(\mathcal{A})$ such that $\vert f_{n} \vert \leq \vert u \vert$. If $u$ is bounded, the limit is uniform.

a) Notice that the functions $u_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k} \mathbb{1}_{[k,k+1)}$ are simple function and therefore measurable. Furthermore $u_{n}(x) \to u(x)$ such that $\vert u_{n}(x)\vert \leq \vert u(x) \vert$. Since $u(x)$ is the pointwise limit of the simple functions $u_{n}(x)$ then $u(x)$ is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable.

Is the above correct?

Comment: What is $u(x)$?

Comment: $u(x)$ is the function given in the second line

Comment: Any suggestions would be appreciated.